# Ajax.BeginForm posts twice if partial view is rendered with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is the scenario:

1. A partial view is retrieved by some JavaScript (AJAX call to controller returning a partial view) and the HTML is added to the DOM
2. The partial view contains a form rendered by `Ajax.BeginForm()`
3. When the form is submitted (submit button clicked), it posts twice

If I render the partial view with the original view with `Html.Partial()` (instead of adding it using JavaScript) the form is only submitted once, as expected.

The script for adding the partial view looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/MyController/MyAction',
   cache: false,
   contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function (result) {
      $('#body').append(result);
   }
});
```

Any ideas? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm an idiot. My controller returned **View** instead of **PartialView** - so of course it contained all the JavaScript resources. In other words, problem was caused by **double unobtrusive script links**. :/